# The number of initial conditions of Cauchy problem for PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations

This number, is it always equal to the order of the differential equation?

in which case, one can reduce this number?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If you are given
$$\frac{{{d^n}y}}{{d{x^n}}} = f(x,y,y',y'', \ldots ,{y^{(n - 1)}})$$
then you need the values of
$$y({x_0}),y'({x_0}),y''({x_0}), \ldots ,{y^{(n - 1)}}({x_0})$$
and the function itself. So you are right -- the number of initial conditions corresponds to the order of the differential equation. But this differential equation can, of course, be reduced to
$$\frac{{dy}}{{dx}} = {y_1},\frac{{d{y_1}}}{{dx}} = {y_2}, \ldots ,\frac{{d{y_{n - 2}}}}{{dx}} = {y_{n - 1}},\frac{{d{y_{n - 1}}}}{{dx}} = f(x,{y_1},{y_2}, \ldots ,{y_{n - 1}})$$
using substitutions
$${y_1} = y',{y_2} = y'', \ldots ,{y_{n - 1}} = {y^{(n - 1)}}.$$

Comment: even in the second formulation (system) we need n condition, where n is the order of the matrix (= order of the equation)

Comment: Yes, we need $n$ conditions.

Comment: what about characteristic Cauchy problems for PDEs? Is it the same?

Comment: What is the characteristic Cauchy problem? Are your referring to the method of characteristics?

Comment: no, I mean when the initial surface is characteritic

Comment: If the initial surface is space-like then the Cauchy problem can be posed, but when the initial surface is a characteristic, solution are not guaranteed to be unique or may not exist if I remember correctly. I am not sure about the number of initial conditions. I think it depends on the PDE and a given surface.